# user authentication in a react native app

Tags: react-native

I'm building a react native app in which users can login. After a user logs in, the server returns a auth token (jwt) which is stored on the device. This all works.

Now, the problem is with authenticating the user whenever something 'happens'.

After the user logs in and the token is stored, he is send to the screen 'Main'. On that screen (and all the other 'secured' screens), I want to check the auth token. I currently have the following function to do this (simplified):

```
// get the auth token out of the redux store
const authToken = useSelector(state => state.auth.authToken)

// the function to authenticate a user
const authenticateUser = () => {
    try {
        fetch('http://URL_TO_SERVER/auth/authenticate-user', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + authToken
            }
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(responseJSON => {
            if (responseJSON.response === 'OK') {
                // user is authenticated
            } else {
                // user is NOT authenticated
            }
        })
}

// only run the function once
useEffect(() => {
    authenticateUser()
}, [])
```

This works, but there is a 'lag' (because fetch returns a promise). When I open the app and go to I screen whilst I'm not logged in, the screen is shown for just a second, and after that, I'm redirected to the login screen. So it works, but I'm not sure that this is the correct way to do so.

I could add a 'layer' to each screen and show a loading modal untill the authenticateUser-function has ran, but I don't think that's the correct way to do so.

My question is: what is the best way to secure screens in a react native app? Is the way I'm doing it OK, or should I switch to another method?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** I have checked the following articles before asking this question.

- [Authentication with React Native and API backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36943253/authentication-with-react-native-and-api-backend)
- https://scotch.io/tutorials/react-native-app-with-authentication-and-user-management-in-15-minutes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to come up with better logic for your auth checks. Usually there is no need to check token every time you open a new screen. Even in your example, you log in and then get sent to a Main screen only to check auth token you've just received. Likewise, should user even see "go to main screen" button when user is clearly not logged in? Do you really want to check for token every time new screen opens in the app? What happens if token is valid by the time you open the screen, but, as the time passes and user stays on the same screen, token becomes invalid?

Try this:

1. create a part of redux store (e.g. reducer) that will handle current authentication state. Simple "isAuthenticated" flag will do for start
2. you can access this flag from any screen that is connected to redux
3. when receiving JWT you can read it's expiration date. So, if you refreshed the token 5 minutes ago and it's not going to expire for the next 2 hours, there is no need to check if token is valid, because you can just assume that by comparing expiration date with current date any time you want
4. use "isAuthenticated" flag to determine whether or not to show the "go to Main screen" button, so that logged out users will not even see that button
5. if you need even more control, hook into navigation to check where user is trying to navigate to and allow/deny that by checking against "isAuthenticated" flag in redux store. Take a look [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/custom-navigators.html) and [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/screen-tracking.html)
6. create a service to keep track on token expiration dates and refresh tokens ahead of time if needed, or periodically check if current token is valid, and set "isAuthenticated" to false if it isn't. Create wrappers around your network functions (fetch in your example) and notify this service if status 401 is received in response to any request to the server so that the service can either refresh the token and repeat request, or let user know that he was logged out

Answer (score 0):

See what i believe is the best way toachieve it is by adding a splashscreen to the app, and there you can divert logic if the token exists you can redirect to Homescreen or loginScreen.

like this :

in Splashscreen.js

```
componentDidMount(){

AsyncStorage.getItem('token') ? navigation.navigate('Home'):navigation.navigate('Login')
}
```

hope it helps.feel free for doubts